# Issue with running application on another machine (not developer's) - mouse click simulating

Tags: c#, wpf, click, mouse, simulator

I've been working on wpf c# application, and application is made for touchscreen monitor/devices,
and in some point of development I needed to implement mouse click from my code (without touching screen) which would triger everytime my
LogInWindow.xaml form loads and I have next issue:

When I run this application on my machine where I am developing it, application works fine, that means -> application is calling my "CLICK" 
function and I can see it's triggering button I want, but when I copied .exe(Debug folder) to another machine because I want to test does it work on 
another machine unfortunately I noticed that
the button I am looking for to be triggered, is not trigering on another machine..just on machine where I am developing application, that is weird..

Here is my code:
*//This is my function which is doing click somewhere on screen, depending on position of control*

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
    SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);

}
```

//Because I want to triger this function everytime my window (form) loads I did this:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

   relativePoint = this.button1.TransformToAncestor(this)
                           .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

   LeftMouseClick((int)relativePoint.X, (int)relativePoint.Y);

    //restOFcode
 }
```

And somehow It wont triger on any of another machines like its not the same code, really weird.

Thanks guys, CHEERS!
:)

Comment: You may want to look into remote debugging.

Comment: Yes that is only solution looks like, I've never tried that but looks like I will try because it's really strange to trigger button on one computer and to not on another one. Only normal explanation for me is that application somehow remember position on first device . example 1700x500px and when I move .exe to bigger or lower monitor we have a issue because control couldn't be found on that location, but I will test it soon! If that is not a problem than we have to do remote debugging...